# Ubuntu 18.4 - Network adaptor running at Half Duplex?

Tags: networking

I upgraded 2 identical Ubuntu servers from 16.4 to 18.4 and now one of them is running at half duplex. I cant find anything on google that applied to 18.04 .

Answer (score 0):

Use mii-tool to set the interface to full duplex:

> mii-tool -F *speed-mode* *interface*

In the following example the speed is "100 mb/s full duplex" and the interface is "enp7s0"

> mii-tool -F 100baseTx-FD enp7s0

To set the interface to gigabit speed, use *1000baseTx-FD* (run "mii-tool" to get the full parameter list).

You can make this command permanent upon reboot, creating a init.d script, or using **/etc/rc.local**.

Create **/etc/rc.local**:

> printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
>   chmod +x /etc/rc.local

Then, edit the **/etc/rc.local** local and insert the **mii-tool** command before the line containing **exit 0**.

Check also the Ethernet cable and the network hub/switch.